# RDL a group for both row & group column

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

i have an RDL contains 1 row group and 1 column group
I want to create one more group which wrap both this 2 group

So that group X will be created, and records of row group A & column group A will generate base on group X.

but i found no solution to add that group X.

Is there any solution to do it? or it is impossible in RDL?

[image]

Above is the expected result with some important points

A is row group, 
C is column group, the string C, C1 ,C2,C3 are actually the data from the same dataset with A, just the grouping parameter is not the same

DATASET
[image]

Below are the interesting requirement:
for each group of A (lets say A1&A2), it will display in a new page (ie. new tabs in the SSRS)
there is total row for each row group member
As mentioned C - C3 are generated dynamically based on the dataset. There are total for each group of A and requires to aggregate the sum for both rows,

thus C somehow need to cater the filtered dataset of A, and display the sum

The problem is:
In the page of A1, C1 & C2 will be blanked. C & C3 contains value
In page A2, C & C3 will be blanked and C1&C2 can be displayed
In fact, for the blank column ( for example A1), even the string C1 & C2 also unable to display as A1 didn't contain the data of C1 & C2 at all

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is not an additional group, but you want to nest your tablix inside of a list object.  There's not any way to add both a column group and a row group inside of a universal grouping unless you use another control item.  Then, you can add the grouping on the list item and it will do what you need. In the image below, you can see that my tablix is inside of a single row of a list object and the list object is grouped by a master ID for this report.  This allows the inner row and column groups to expand as necessary, but separates them based on the master ID.  I also put page breaks on this list item to put each ID on a new page.

[image]

Comment: i think i cannot achieve what i wanted, it is correct that adding another table inside one table can achieve "filtered column", just like the previous answer, the problem is, that item cannot beautifully display, i have shown a simple in the updated question